# ArrayList in ActionListener isnt working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i have made a java program named `DoctorsCare` in which patients can book their appointment with a doctor. So in the appointment panel I have included patient id, name, gender, date of birth, address and a brief patient history.

All these string values will be taken in an array list and will eventually be returned to a new tab (Doctors tab) after the appointment form is filled and the submit button is clicked. the the array list code I wrote has some problems but I can run the program.

I just need to know where I made the mistake and how can I return the array list values to the doctors tab.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame1= new JFrame();
    JTextField id;
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Patient ID:");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Name:");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Gender:");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Date of Birth:");
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Address:");
    JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Phone:");
    JLabel label6= new JLabel("brief patient history:");
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JTextArea phistry = new JTextArea(11,31);
    JTextField text1 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text3 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text4 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text5 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField text6 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text7 = new JTextField(20);
    JButton button = new JButton("SUBMIT");

    NewPage()
    {
        frame1.setTitle("Booking Appointment");      
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(330,470);
        frame1.add(panel1);
        panel1.add(label);

        panel1.add(text1);
        panel1.add(label2);
        panel1.add(text2);
        panel1.add(label3);
        panel1.add(text3);
        panel1.add(label4);
        panel1.add(text4);
        panel1.add(label5);
        panel1.add(text5);
        panel1.add(label7);
        panel1.add(text7);
        panel1.add(label6);
        panel1.add(phistry);
        panel1.add(button);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160,40));
        button.addActionListener(this);             
    }



    \\the button code
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     

        List<List<String>> model = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); 

        text1.selectAll(); \\selects the input from user
        text2.selectAll();
        text3.selectAll();
        text4.selectAll();
        text5.selectAll();
        text6.selectAll();
        String ID = text1.getSelectedText(); \\initializes ID
        String PName = text2.getSelectedText();
        String Gender = text3.getSelectedText();
        String DoB = text4.getSelectedText();
        String Address = text5.getSelectedText();
        //String phone = text7.getSelectedText();
        String phistry = text6.getSelectedText();

        //String phistry = text6.getSelectedText();

        List<String> line = Arrays.asList(new String[]{ID, PName, Gender, DoB, Address, phistry});
        model.add(line);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ID\tFirst\tLast\tCourse\tYear\n");
        for(List<String> input : model) {
            for (String item : input) {
                sb.append(item);
                if (input.indexOf(item) == input.size()-1) {
                    sb.append("\n");
                } else {
                    sb.append("\t");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "some problems" "does not work" .. could you translate that to more technical terminology?

Comment: Give a [mcve]. What specific problems does it have when you run it?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with that selectAll()? just use getText() on all the fields.

Comment: @Stultuske i want the actionlistener to get the array list values to another tab. how do i do that?

Comment: You already have those values in the Model, move the model as instance variable, and try passing it to the next tab.

Comment: @Saran thanks ill try that.

Comment: @code_buoy22 do you want to move it to the next tab or also want to display the values in TextArea?. Because I could see you haven't utilized the JTextArea instance you have created.

Comment: @Praveen yes i want to move it to the next tab but now im thinking if i keep the list in a button it will be much convenient. how do you suppose i do that?

Comment: you can create the list as a static variable and use it across anywhere you want it.

Comment: @utkarsh31 thanks for that idea. :)

Comment: @utkarsh31 until you understand the perils of making things `static`, please stop giving any advice on it.

Comment: @AndrewThomson I understand the perils which come with static and would have handled them accordingly... There are always multiple ways to solve a problem

Comment: *"and would have handled them accordingly...* It's more relevant what the OP would have done. **This is not about you.**

Comment: @AndrewThomson that's what I was going to warn him about before you interrupted me.. But as u have already mentioned it maybe u can explain better..

Comment: @code_buoy22 Do you have the Doctors tab as a separate class?

Comment: @Praveen yes Doctors tab is in a separate class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `List` contains the model information, but you haven't set it in the text area you have like below in the `actionPerformed` method,

```
this.phistry.setText(sb.toString());
```

Assuming that you have the Doctors tab in a separate class like below (else you can set the model directly in the `NewFrame`,

```
class DoctorsPanel extends JPanel {

    private List<List<String>> model;
    JTextArea history;

    public DoctorsPanel() {
        model = new LinkedList<>();
        history = new JTextArea(11, 31);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        add(history);
    }

    public void setModel(List<List<String>> model) {
        this.model = model;
        setHistory();
    }

    private void setHistory() {
        this.history.setText(getModelData());
    }

    private String getModelData() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ID\tFirst\tLast\tCourse\tYear\n");
        for (List<String> input : model) {
            for (String item : input) {
                sb.append(item);
                if (input.indexOf(item) == input.size() - 1) {
                    sb.append("\n");
                } else {
                    sb.append("\t");
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

You can have your tabbed pane like below in the `NewFrame`,

```
 JTabbedPane jTab = new JTabbedPane();
 panel1 = new JPanel();
 panel2=new DoctorsPanel();
 jTab.add("Book", panel1);
 jTab.add("Doctors", panel2);
 frame1.add(jTab);
```

Then you can set it whenever the appointment is made. 
i.e. when an action performed on tab1 component

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     

        List<List<String>> model = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); 

        String ID = text1.getText();
        String PName = text2.getText();
        String Gender = text3.getText();
        String DoB = text4.getText();
        String Address = text5.getText();
        String phistry = text6.getText();

        List<String> line = Arrays.asList(new String[]{ID, PName, Gender, DoB, Address, phistry});
        model.add(line);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ID\tFirst\tLast\tCourse\tYear\n");
        for(List<String> input : model) {
            for (String item : input) {
                sb.append(item);
                if (input.indexOf(item) == input.size()-1) {
                    sb.append("\n");
                } else {
                    sb.append("\t");
                }
            }
        }
        this.phistry.setText(sb.toString());//sets the text in tab1
        panel2.setModel(model);//sets the model in Doctors panel
    }
```

But I suggest to keep the variable *model* `List` at class `NewFrame` as a member rather than a local variable to hold the previously added information

Comment: the last line "panel2.setModel(model);" is showing compilation error and so when i used this line after the setModel method in the Doctors Panel class, it still shows a compilation error.

Comment: @code_buoy22 Where did you used the `setModel` call?. As per your code the model variable is local and only works in `actionPerformed` method. If you want to use globally then declare it as the member of the class `NewFrame`

Comment: I am not sure, If we can chat outside. Can you try this [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: i called the setModel in the DoctorsPanel  class. just after defining setModel.

Comment: @code_buoy22 Could you please post your minimal code to understand what you are trying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159756/discussion-between-code-buoy22-and-praveen).